# Non RAM based in-browser database solutions?

Tags: database-design, storage-engine, database-engine, javascript

I want to decentralize my databases and upload it to [Sia Skynet](https://siasky.net) to give the users the ability to search on front-end. It is important to be able to deal with large amounts of data, but the RAM-based in-browser SQL engines (MiniSearch, AlaSQL, etc) are limited.

Yeaterday I made a demo: I sorted and partitioned my key-value database into 1000 line files and I made an [index](https://siasky.net/NAC25yabWhK7AF0h0uJ-rrgAlIl0uyQnx8jQAhdJWVjqtw/data/index.txt) for the files also. You can try out my [demo here](https://siasky.net/NAC25yabWhK7AF0h0uJ-rrgAlIl0uyQnx8jQAhdJWVjqtw/), or check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/DaWe35/SkyLookup)

So my question is that are there any better solutions for large-in-browser databases? (I don't really want to reinvent the wheel )

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. All you do is promote Skynet. I see no question, no solution.  Even your GitHub pointer contains nothing but just more promotion: not a single line of code or anything that shows how to use your service.

Comment: I’m not denigrating the Skynet service. It looks interesting. But stack exchange is NOT the place to promote it (or anything else) and definitely so blatantly.

Comment: Have you read my last line? It is a question. I don't want to promote anything, how can I ask without not showing what I want to do?

Comment: I'm thinking about removing the Skynet link, but them the whole question loses its sense. People will not understand why this idiot wants to store a DB in static files

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind In this question I mentioned Skynet, MiniSearch, AlaSQL, and even my repo GitHub repo. All of them are open sources and related to the question. Why is Skynet a promotion, while the others are not?